# how to fetch data from JIRA using PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, jira

how to fetch data from JIRA (Bug tracking tool) using PHP application? is it possible or not?
Thanks,
Sagar.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if this helps you in your find:

http://codingx.blogspot.com/2011/04/play-with-jira-api-from-php.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of PHP clients that implement the SOAP interface so you can post issues, create users, execute searches using JQL, and anything else provided by the API. One such project is on GitHub at https://github.com/cpliakas/jira-client, and it is also available as a Composer package on Packagist.org at https://packagist.org/packages/cpliakas/jira.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use the SOAP api for jira at `http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+RPC+Services`

Your best bet is probably to try the built in php soap client.